# Checks if an input , a string, has Roman numerals

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean

A function that takes, as input, a string and returns true if that string contains only
Roman numerals and false otherwise. Recall, the Roman numerals are M, D, C, L,
X, V, and I.

this is what i have so far

```
bool isRoman(string str, char key)
 {

 assert(str.length() > 0)

 if(length[i] == key)
  {

  return i;
  } 
 }
```

Comment: What is `i`? What is `key`?

Comment: At least you've made a start.  There looks to be some errors here, namely the use of the undefined variable `i`, and not all control paths of the function returning a value.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Your title says "Sort a string".  But then your description mentions nothing about sorting.

Comment: assert() will only be caught in debug mode... Release will not hit that. I would suggest doing something like if(str.empty()) { return false; } Then continue ...

Comment: basically i have to create a function that takes in a string of roman numerals and checks if it has roman numerals

Comment: Reminder to check against words like "callable, livid and climb", which have Roman Numeral letters but are not numbers.

Comment: @JE3 *true if that string contains only Roman numerals* -- Are you sure you're reading the description correctly?  Here is a string -- "LLLLLL" -- is that a Roman numeral?  Or here is another string -- "XX II" -- that contains Roman numerals, two of them.  So you need to clarify a little bit more as to what this assignment is supposed to do.

Comment: @JE3 I really think the assignment is much more than seeing if a string has "M", "L", etc.  That would be just too simple.  Just the mentioning of "Roman Numeral" seems to me that you should be testing if the roman numeral(s) in the string are valid.  Yes, check if the letters are "M", "L", etc. but it takes more than that to verify a roman numeral is valid.

Comment: @PaulMckenzie yes the assignment is to create 3 functions, one that checks if the string only contains roman numeral , second, a function to take in a character that is a roman numeral , and return its value, and lastly a function that converts a roman numeral into a arabic numeral, and takes the roman numeral and adds them up from left to right to build a sum

Comment: @JE3 -- So it is much more than simply checking if a string contains M, L, X, etc.  If I were you, I would just assume the string contains a valid roman numeral, and work on a conversion to Arabic numeral, and convert from Arabic back to Roman numeral.  Work on the validation further along, otherwise you may never finish the assignment.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie im trying to figure out how make the function to find the value of the character entered

Answer (score 1):

A demo that uses no extra standard library.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isRoman(string s){
    if(s.empty()){
        throw std::runtime_error("Got empty string");
    }
    bool isAllRoman = true;
    for(const auto& c: s){
        if(isspace(c)) //if you need to skip whitspace 
            continue;  
        if(!(c == 'M' || c == 'D' || c == 'C' || 
        c == 'L' || c == 'X' || c == 'V' || c == 'I')){
            isAllRoman = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isAllRoman;
}
```

Leave a comment if you have anything don't understand.

Comment: You can return false instead of `isAllRoman = false`. No need for the `bool`ean.

Comment: it is best to have one return path per function.... I like the way it is.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI In your opinion, perhaps. Thats a topic that is highly disputed.

Comment: @Rick Don't pass potentially negative values to functions from `<cctype>`.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI If the function returns before throwing it won't throw. Sorry but you are talking bs.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know whether a `std::string` contains only values from a specific set of valid characters you can use [`std::string::find_first_not_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of). That makes your function a one-liner:

```
bool isRoman(const std::string &str)
{
    return !str.empty() && str.find_first_not_of("MDCLXVI") == std::string::npos;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::string_literals;

bool is_roman(std::string_view sv)
{                             // if the character is not found in the string
    for(auto const &ch : sv) //  containing roman numeric symbols, return false.
        if ("MDCLXVI"s.find(std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned>(ch))) == std::string::npos)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I would call strupr(number), instead of std::toupper() every function call per char.

Comment: You could use `std::transform` with `std::toupper` to convert the string first.

Comment: Also I don't like this function. It doesn't work properly. What if number is null and it will skip over the while(*number) and return true.... Function should be isRoman() no one will ever make functions with _ between them (that is more of a variable name)

Comment: @OmidCompSCI `strupr()` isn't standard.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Does unnecessary work if the loop exits early.

Comment: @Swordfish, don't update answers without explanations. Also assert() will be called in debug mode not release, this will not work... and the function will not return anything if assert() fails. This should be handled by returning false if it is empty.... There is nothing wrong with calling the function if an empty string is passed in

Comment: @OmidCompSCI When the pointer is a null-pointer and the function expects a pointer to a string it is a violation of the precondition which should be dealt with while debugging. That should never happen in release builds. "the function will not return anything if assert() fails" no need to return anything in that case since the program will terminate.

Comment: @Swordfish, and not all cases/workflows are handled, so when this goes out to customers in release, the function will end up returning true, and could cause bad workflows or a bad state of a program to think it is true and do whatever.... This is an easy scenario, we have to think outside the box on a bigger picture

Comment: @OmidCompSCI If the precondition states that the argument must point to a zero terminated string and it does not, the calling code has a problem, not this function. "no one will ever make functions with _ between them" again: Your opinion.

Comment: @Swordfish, there could be a MILLION WAYS that the string might become null, even if ALL CODE that you are reading/seeing looks like it is passing something in. There could be multithreaded environments or OTHER bad workflows, that cause destructors or something to be called, and that variable that is being passed in was some pointer in a class that got destructed DUE TO ANOTHER BAD WORKFLOW that was not caught and is a bug. Your statement is wrong.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI "DUE TO ANOTHER BAD WORKFLOW" You name it yourself: Something other than this function misbehaves.

Comment: @Swordfish, YES!!!! AND WHAT IF IT IS A BUG THAT HAS NOT BEEN CAUGHT AND THE SOFTWARE WAS RELEASED. IT WAS AN UNINTENTIONAL VALUE PASSED IN. THE FUNCTION NEEDS TO HANDLE THIS.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Stop telling me your opinions. And stop shouting for gods sake.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI No one will ever make function names with "_" in them? Have you looked at the C++ standard library?